# pandas: counting all intersections between pair of keys

Tags: python, pandas

I am playing with pandas and am having an issue figuring out how to solve the following problem. Given a dataframe of bookId and readerId, I would like to get, for a given A reader, the  number of other readers who have read any of the book A has read.

This is a sample dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'bookId': [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],
                   'readerId': [1,2,1,3,1,3,4,1,3,4,5,6]})
```

Can someone help me with this or maybe give me the intuition for solving it when using pandas?
A new dataframe with a readerId and count columns would be the output.

**Update:**

Actually rather than getting the count of reader of each book, I would like to get a count of all readers who read any books I have read. so if a reader read 3 books and 20 others read any of these books then I would really want to have 20 as the answer, were all 20 readers are distinct and didn't necessarily read ALL the given reader's book list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the count for each reader, something like this should work:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'bookId': [1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],
   ...:                  'readerId': [1,2,1,3,1,3,4,1,3,4,5,6]})

In [3]: res = pd.DataFrame(np.unique(df.readerId)).reset_index(drop=True)

In [4]: def get_readers(reader, df=df):
    ...:     return len(set(df.readerId[df.bookId.isin(df.bookId[
    ...:                                     df.readerId==reader])]))-1

In [5]: res['Count'] = res.readerId.apply(get_readers)

In [6]: res
Out[6]: 
   readerId  Count
0         1      5
1         2      1
2         3      4
3         4      4
4         5      4
5         6      4

In [7]: timeit get_readers(1)
1000 loops, best of 3: 387 us per loop
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to use a groupby of some sort to get a dataframe of [readerId,Count] without iterating through each readers one at a time?

Comment: Thanks for the additional edit. my initial dataframe is very large (millions of rows). Any idea how this method scales to large dataframes?

Comment: @ak3nat0n -- I will remove the test timing as I am not sure they are really adequate...it is possible that you need to more customized algorithm if performance is important, but it will probably take more work.

Answer (score 1):

There should be many ways to solve your problem. Here's mine, might not be the best one:

### First, get the bookIds of reader1

```
In [99]: bookIds = df[df['readerId']==1]['bookId'].values

In [100]: bookIds
Out[100]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

If yor are familiar with SQL, you can think it as: `SELECT bookId FROM df WHERE readerId == 1`

### Second, select those readerId == 1 and bookId is in the above `bookIds` array

```
In [101]: df2 = df[df['readerId'] != 1 & df['bookId'].isin(bookIds)]

In [102]: df2 
Out[102]: 
    bookId  readerId
1        1         2   
3        2         3   
5        3         3   
6        3         4   
8        4         3   
9        4         4   
10       4         5   
11       4         6
```

SQL: `SELECT bookId, readerId FROM df WHERE readerId != 1 and bookId in bookIds`

### Last, Group it by readerId and count them

```
In [103]: df2.groupby('readerId').size()
Out[103]: 
readerId
2           1   
3           3   
4           2   
5           1
6           1
dtype: int64
```

SQL: `SELECT COUNT(bookId) FROM df2 GROUP BY readerId`

Hope it might help you to learn pandas easier

## [EDIT], To answer what you ask in the comment:

### Create another dataframe (only change the column)

```
In [114]: df2 = df.rename(columns={'readerId': 'otherReaderId'})
```

### Join them by `bookId`, and then group them by `readerId` and `otherReaderId`

```
In [115]: pd.merge(df, df2, on='bookId').groupby(['readerId', 'otherReaderId']).size()
Out[115]: 
readerId  otherReaderId
1         1                4
          2                1
          3                3
          4                2
          5                1
          6                1
2         1                1
          2                1
3         1                3
          3                3
          4                2
          5                1
          6                1
4         1                2
          3                2
          4                2
          5                1
          6                1
5         1                1
          3                1
          4                1
          5                1
          6                1
6         1                1
          3                1
          4                1
          5                1
          6                1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the quick answer. Is it possible to use the groupby  method to create a new dataframe containing all readers and the count of the shared readers? or do I need to do it iteratively?

Comment: You, you can join the dataframe to itself, and then some groupby tricks might achieve your goal.